# SetImageResource() do not just works at the second time in a loop

Tags: android

Well! I made a code that set a new imageView each time the sound ends and I verify it with a While loop the it just works at the second time. I already tried with a switch but it didnt works.

```
av = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ave_maria);
    av.start();

    salve = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.salve_rainha);

    im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imag1);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                // YouActivity
                GozososActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        if (av.isPlaying()) {

                        } else {
                            avemarias++;
                            if(avemarias > 10){
                                salve.start();
                            }else{
                                im.setImageResource(R.drawable.primeiro_misterio_gozoso+avemarias);

                                av.start();             
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are reaching the command? Also, a + isn't valid in an id tag, that might cause issues. `R.drawable.primeiro_misterio_gozoso+avemarias`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code line,

```
im.setImageResource(R.drawable.primeiro_misterio_gozoso+avemarias);
```

You are doing some of two integer numbers.

So is there any resource available for that number? (Look in R.java file if not then the method does not work)

For `setImageResource()` Android only set the resource as drawable which has `int` entry in `R.java` or in `android.R` file.

Comment: I have each resource that i need for example  R.drawable.primeiro_misterio_gozoso+01); R.drawable.primeiro_misterio_gozoso+02);  ...

Comment: But I think you don't have a **resource** which has `int` value equal to sum of `R.drawable.primeiro_misterio_gozoso+avemarias` these two int. Look at your application's `R.java` file.